# How to convert string to dictionary to retrieve one value from it?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

One of my function returns the string  'sumstr' as declared in below function 'def convert_st(self)' :

```
def covert_st(self):
    sumstr= 'Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On'
    dd ={}
    for st in sumstr:
        key,value=st.split(',')
        dd[key] = value
    print dd
    print dd['Email']
```

I am trying to convert the string 'sumstr'  to dictionary and read the value of 'Email' .
But I am getting Error :  "in covert_st ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to assign 3 values to 2 values, that was the issue, First you need to split by , and then by : to separate first the keys and finally the key values.

```
def covert_st():
    sumstr= 'Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On'
    sumstr = sumstr.split(',')
    dd ={}
    for st in sumstr:
        key,value=st.split(':')
        dd[key] = value
    print dd
    print dd['Email']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foo = 'Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On'
bar = dict(item.strip().split(': ') for item in foo.split(','))
print(bar['Email'])
```

Note that your string has inconsistent commas, e.g. `,` and `,`. That is why you need to use also strip(). If they were consistent you can split the foo string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If sumstr can be json, then you can easily parse it like so:

```
import json
sumstr= '{Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On}'
data = json.loads(sumstr)
email = data["Email"]
```

If sumstr cannot be json formatted then you can parse it like so:

```
sumstr= 'Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On'
elements = sumstr.split(",")
email = elements[0].split(":")[1].strip()
```

Comment: Note that even with added curly braces '{Email: testmail@gmail.com ,Status: Connected, Logstate: On}' is not valid json, so your first suggestion will not work.